# Display list of items within Telerik grid using MVC AJAX Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, telerik

For each row in my grid, I am loading fields from my view model.  One of the fields in my view model is a List which will have anywhere from 1-4 strings.  I cannot figure out how to write the code for that column such that it will print out a single string (or bulletted list of the strings for each item in the List collection).

here is my razor view (index.cshtml)

```
<div>
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<KbEditor.Models.QuestionViewModel>()
      .Name("grid")
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Questions_GridListAll", "Questions"))
            .PageSize(20)
      )
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
            columns.Bound(model => model.QuestionID).ClientTemplate("<a href='" + Url.Action("Details", "Questions") + "/#= QuestionID #'" + ">#=QuestionID#</a>");
            columns.Bound(model => model.Question1);
            columns.Bound(model => model.PrimaryKeyword)
                         .ClientTemplate(  "<table class='table'> 
                                              foreach( var item in model ) 
                                                  foreach( var str in item.keywordstringlist) 
                                                {<tr>#str</tr>}
                                            </table>" );
      })
      .Pageable() // Enable paging
      .Sortable() // Enable sorting
     )
</div>
```

I can't seem to figure out anyway that i can take the items from the list and get them populated in the final column of the grid.